# Kendo UI grid with Django

Tags: django, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to show my model list with using Kendo UI. But it gives me error in browser console. I took the list as json. Please help me to solve this problem.

**template**

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: { //"https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                    url: "{% url 'test_json' %}",
                    dataType: "json",
                }
            },
            schema: {
                total: "count",
                data: "results",
            },
            pageSize: 5
        },
        height: 550,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "id",
            width: 240
        }, {
            field: "book",
        }, {
            field: "no_of_page",
        }]
    });
```

**views.py**

```
def test_json(request):
books = Book.objects.all().values('id','name','no_of_page')
booklist = list(books)
return JsonResponse(booklist,  safe=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^test/book/$', test_json, name='test_json'),
```

Answer (score 0):

## views.py

```
def test_json(request):
books = Book.objects.all().values('id','name','no_of_page')
booklist = list(books)
content = {
  'results' : booklist,
  'count' : booklist.count()
}
return JsonResponse(content,  safe=False)
```

Comment: adding explanation to the code will make it more acceptable and attracts more votes

Comment: In addition to an explanation, you'll want to properly format your code example.